# save new position of marker from draggable marker - google maps V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have success to get new position of dragable marker..
In my code below I can create newmarker by rightclick, and then I can save the marker by click the save button at infowindow of the marker...
But the problem is I can't insert the new coordinates (latitude and longitude) into the form at infowindow...

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var newmarker;

function geocodePosition(pos) {
  geocoder.geocode({
    latLng: pos
  }, function(responses) {
    if (responses && responses.length > 0) {
      updateMarkerAddress(responses[0].formatted_address);
    } else {
      updateMarkerAddress('Cannot determine address at this location.');
    }
  });
}

function updateMarkerStatus(str) {
  document.getElementById('markerStatus').innerHTML = str;
}

function updateMarkerPosition(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lat(),
    latLng.lng()
  ].join(', ');
}
function updateMarkerLat(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('latnew').innerHTML = [
     latLng.lat()
  ];
}
function updateMarkerLng(latLng) {
  document.getElementById('lngnew').innerHTML = [
    latLng.lng()
  ];
}

function updateMarkerAddress(str) {
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = str;
}

function initialize() {
  var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.8,110.3666667);
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: latLng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });


  google.maps.event.addListener(map, "rightclick", function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });


    function placeMarker(location) {
        var newmarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map,
            draggable: true
        });


        var form = 
            '<div id="bodyContent">'+
            '<b>New Map</b>' +
            '<form method="post">'+
            '<table>'+
            '<tr><td>Name place :<input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>'+
            '<tr><td>Latitude :<input type="text" name="latitude" value="latnew"/></td></tr>'+
            '<tr><td>Longitude: <input type="text" name="longitude" value="lngnew"/></td></tr>'+
            '<tr><td><input type="submit" value="save"></td></tr>'+
            '</table>'+
            '</form>'+
            '</div>';

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: form,
            maxWidth :500
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,newmarker);
            //marker1.openInfoWindowHtml('Some text', {noCloseOnClick: 'false'});
        });

        // Update current position info.
        updateMarkerPosition(latLng);
        updateMarkerLat(latLng);
        updateMarkerLng(latLng);
        geocodePosition(latLng);

        // Add dragging event listeners.
        google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker, 'dragstart', function() {
            updateMarkerAddress('Dragging...');
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker, 'drag', function() {
            updateMarkerStatus('Dragging...');
            updateMarkerPosition(newmarker.getPosition());
            updateMarkerLat(newmarker.getPosition());
            updateMarkerLng(newmarker.getPosition());
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker, 'dragend', function() {
            updateMarkerStatus('Drag ended');
            geocodePosition(newmarker.getPosition());
            updateMarkerLat(newmarker.getPosition());
            updateMarkerLng(newmarker.getPosition());
        });
    }


}

// Onload handler to fire off the app.
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
  #mapCanvas {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
    float: left;
  }
  #infoPanel {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  #infoPanel div {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
  </style>

  <div id="mapCanvas"></div>
  <div id="infoPanel">
    <b>Marker status:</b>

    <div id="markerStatus"><i>Click and drag the marker.</i></div>
    <b>Current position:</b>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <div id="latnew"></div><div id="lngnew"></div>
    <b>Closest matching address:</b>
    <div id="address"></div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

any ideas of this problem?
thanks before...

Mahendra,

Answer (score 1):

You can put the values of the textboxes to the latitude and longitude of the marker when first created by "embedding" them in the form string you are building like this:

```js
var form = 
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    '<b>New Map</b>' +
    '<form method="post">'+
    '<table>'+
    '<tr><td>Name place :<input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>'+
    '<tr><td>Latitude :<input type="text" name="latitude" value="' + newmarker.position.lat() + '"/></td></tr>'+
    '<tr><td>Longitude: <input type="text" name="longitude" value="' + newmarker.position.lng() + '"/></td></tr>'+
    '<tr><td><input type="submit" value="save"></td></tr>'+
    '</table>'+
    '</form>'+
    '</div>';
```

But you then still have a problem that the values aren't updated when the marker has been dragged.

You can solve that by putting the declaration of your form and infowindow variables inside the click handler like this:

```js
google.maps.event.addListener(newmarker, 'click', function() {
    var form = 
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '<b>New Map</b>' +
        '<form method="post">'+
        '<table>'+
        '<tr><td>Name place :<input type="text" name="name"/></td></tr>'+
        '<tr><td>Latitude :<input type="text" name="latitude" value="' + newmarker.position.lat() + '"/></td></tr>'+
        '<tr><td>Longitude: <input type="text" name="longitude" value="' + newmarker.position.lng() + '"/></td></tr>'+
        '<tr><td><input type="submit" value="save"></td></tr>'+
        '</table>'+
        '</form>'+
        '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: form,
        maxWidth :500
    });

    infowindow.open(map,newmarker);
});
```

Comment: You'll still have a problem though... you can drag a marker while the infowindow is open (in that case the values will not be updated). You will have to add an id to those input controls on the form, and update their values using the DOM (and that only if the infowindow of the marker you're currently dragging is open). I'll leave that as an exercise ;-)