# Allowing a user to click on a google map to pinpoint a location (lat / long) to be used as form data (storing in SQL database)

Tags: google-maps, latitude-longitude

My GoogleFu has failed me, all the results I'm getting are people who accept lat/longs in text fields and need to generate a map... I need the **opposite** of that.

I want my users to:

- Load the page, see a small clickable google map as a part of a form
- Click on that map, or "drag" an already existing map marker to a new location
- Once the form is submitted, I want the  LAT + LONG of the map markers location (it's **updated** position, after it's been dragged) to be inserted into an SQL database.

I can't seem to find any guides or documentation online that would let me achieve something like this; would anybody mind pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the lat lng from a geocoded address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944681/how-to-find-the-lat-lng-from-a-geocoded-address)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you click on a map and have latitude and longitude fields in a form populated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1726049/how-do-you-click-on-a-map-and-have-latitude-and-longitude-fields-in-a-form-popul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a input to the form(may be hidden) and observe either the `click`-event of the map(when creating a new marker) or the `dragend`-event of the existing marker.

In the callback of both events a [`google.maps.MouseEvent`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#MouseEvent) is available which contains the related [`LatLng`-object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en#LatLng), which may be used to set the value of the input(not directly, it's not a string, use e.g. `latLng.toString()` or build another string that fits your needs).