# Google map how to display a dragable marker based on coordinates and return new coordinates

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have to write a script for **Google Maps V3** which will do the following:

- Place a marker on a map based on a set of coordinates and possbibly change the address after the page has been loaded
- Allow the user the drag the mark to replace it elsewhere
- Collect the new coordinates once the marker has been moved.

The first part is basic enough and should be fine, changing the address after the page is loaded should only be a matter of calling back the same function?
I am not sure where to start on the draggable marker and collecting hew coordinates.

Would anyone know of scripts / API's or where in the doc should I start?

Comment: Have you tried searching SO? Both [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6510781/google-maps-v3-need-multiple-draggable-markers-to-update-html-input-fields) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645151/save-new-position-of-marker-from-draggable-marker-google-maps-v3) from a search for draggable marker coordinates in the [google-maps-api-3] tag seem relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [Google Maps Javascript API V3 Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference) to see whether the google.maps.Marker class has :

- a `draggable` option
- an `dragend` event
- a `getPosition` method

Hint: The answer might just be "yes" to all three, and you don't need much else to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes I have but the document provides row info with little on how to use those. Is there examples / samples of those used somewhere.
I seem to remember than on previous versions all elements had more explanations and even demos.
A little lost on it to tell you the truth.

Comment: You probably want to browse through some of the [Code Samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/) to get you started.